# How do I convert my dataframe column into vectors using word2vec?

Tags: python, pandas, word-embeddings, word2vec

I have the column of Categories of vary length in my DataFrame as shown below :

```
Categories

[Restaurants , Drinks]
[Restaurants , Drinks , Rooftop]
[Dinner]
.
.
.
```

How do I convert this column into word2vec embedding ?